# App Icon does not show up

Tags: android

My app icon shows up on my Nexus One, but not on the Android Market site or the emulator. Is there some naming convention to use?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a convention, it uses what ever icon you have listed in your AndroidManifest.xml.  It should look like this:

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/my_icon">
```

and then you should have an image file in your res/drawable directory called my_icon.png

Comment: Thanks, that's what I've done, but the emulator does not show it. On my phone it shows up fine. Must be an emulator quirk.